# Draft issue when publishing app on google paly console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am trying to publish an app on google play console. It shows me "App Status" is "Draft" and "Update Status" is In Review". Is it ok?

[My Google Play Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaCS8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Select your *app* by clicking on its name. This will take you to the screen where you filled out the information for your store listing. A multitude of menu options can be found on the left side of the screen. Select Pricing and Distribution from the drop-down menu. Scroll down to the bottom of the page to acknowledge that the software conforms with US Export Laws and that it meets the Content Guidelines. Before you click any of the buttons, read the information for each one to make sure your program complies. You have to complete all the requirements.